# Passing Google Spreadsheet value from Google Apps script to HTML returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am having trouble passing a value from a Google Spreadsheet to a Javascript function on the HTML.

code.gs

```html
function getSiteCoords()
{
     var emailA = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var employeesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Employees") // data pertaining to employees

   var numRows=1;
     while(employeesheet.getRange("A"+numRows+":A"+numRows).getValue() != "") //this will count the number of rows that are filled
     {
       if(employeesheet.getRange("A"+numRows).getValue()===emailA)
       {
         let coords = employeesheet.getRange("E"+numRows).getValue();
         return coords;
       }
         numRows = numRows+1;
     }
    return "";
}
```

index.html

```html
function checkPosition(position) {
  console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
  " Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);

  var lat= 54.978 ;
  var long=-1.5622;
  
  var coords = google.script.run.getSiteCoords();
  console.log("Site Coords " + coords);
  let calc= Math.sqrt(Math.pow(position.coords.latitude - lat , 2) + Math.pow(position.coords.longitude - long , 2));
  console.log("calc: "+ calc);
  if(calc>0.005)
  window.location.replace("https://google.com");
}
```

No matter what, the coords on index.html returns undefined.

Comment: One issue with your code is that there are no active sheets for a script deployed as a web app.  You will need to use something like `SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx').getSheetByName("Employees")`

Comment: Hello @SalahAndalusi, just like @gries has mentioned, I suggest you to use the `openById` method since it is uncommon for scripts bound to sheets to be used as web-apps. Are you still getting the error after the change? Cheers!

Comment: Thank you everyone. I managed to resolve the issue by opening the spreadsheet in code.gs and using the Google API call management functions. After a bit of elbow grease it's working as intended.